# Lighting issue only on another device

Tags: opengl, hardware, lighting, deferred-rendering

I developed an OpenGL game in C++ on my desktop machine, where no errors occurred. Now compiling and running it on my tablet, the lighting is messed up. This is my lighting buffer.

[image: the lighting calculation is incorrect]

I use deferred rendering, so I have positions and normals as textures. As pointed out in an answer below, the reason for the lighting issue is that instead of the normal texture, the position texture is used for the calculation.

Some facts about the environments. Both machines run Windows 8 Pro 64bit. The video cards are a Nvidia Geforce 560 on the desktop and a Intel HD Graphics 4000 on the tablet. The G-buffer textures, normals and positions in this case, are intact on the tablet and are not mixed up. There are no OpenGL errors.

This is my lighting shader.

```
#version 330

in vec2 coord;
out vec3 image;

uniform int type = 1;

uniform sampler2D positions;
uniform sampler2D normals;
uniform vec3 light;
uniform vec3 color;
uniform float radius;
uniform float intensity = 1.0;

void main()
{
    if(type == 0) // directional light
    {
        vec3 normal = texture2D(normals, coord).xyz;
        float fraction = max(dot(normalize(light), normal) / 2.0 + 0.5, 0);
        image = intensity * color * fraction;
    }
    else if(type == 1) // point light
    {
        // ...
    }
    else if(type == 2) // spot light
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is the code I use to bind the sampler uniforms. `Pass->Samplers` is an `unordered_map<string, GLuint>` which maps texture target ids to shader locations. `Pass->Program` holds the shader program id.

```
glUseProgram(Pass->Program);

int n = 0; for(auto i : Pass->Samplers)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + n);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i.second);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(Pass->Program, i.first.c_str()), n);
    n++;
}
```

Why are the samplers for positions and normals mixed up on the tablet machine? What am I doing wrong?

Update: After updating my operating system to Windows 8.1, I noticed that the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like is is using the position data instead of the normal data for lighting. Might the textures have been mixed up (you might find the sampler uniforms are at different locations between your desktop at tablet)?

Comment: Wow, that would make sense. How can I check that? I use exactly the same source code on both machines. However, maybe I unintentionally make use of an undefined behavior that accidentally works correct on my desktop...

Comment: You probably want to do something like `GLint norm = glGetUniformLocation(prog_id, "normals" );` (and the same for "positions"). That will get you the uniform locations. You then need to set each to the texture _unit_ you are using for each texture (NOT the texture id).

Comment: I did that check. On desktop the locations are `3` for `normals` and `4` for positions. On tablet the locations are `1183` and `1186`. Shouldn't they actually be `0` and `1`? I added the binding code to my question.

Comment: Your binding code looks OK (assuming you've called `glUseProgram(Pass->Program)` before calling it). You're also not making either of the mistakes I thought you might be (because I've made them myself). It still looks like the position data is used instead of the normal data. Is there anywhere else they might get mixed up? in the FBO attachment?

Comment: I don't think you can read too much into the actual location values - I'm guessing the Nvidia driver sorts them alphabetically. The ones returned by the Intel driver look odd, but as far as I know they're OK.

Comment: Yes, I use the shader program before binding the uniforms. I rendered the g-buffer textures to screen to make sure that they aren't mixed up. The odd uniform locations are reproducable. Do you have any idea how to further debug this issue?

Comment: Could it have to do with the need to skip shader locations for uniforms with multiple channels? I am not completely sure if this is correct, but I just remembered that I've read something about this.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm just about out of ideas. Are you rendering to the same FBO you used to generate the normal data? If so, is the normal texture still attached to it? It shouldn't matter if you're not drawing to it, but you never know...

Comment: Hmmm... I might be wrong about the normal/position mix-up. Looking at the bottom picture, I wonder if the light type is getting mixed up. Does your shader actually have code for the other light-types? If so you could try commenting them out (and the type test).

Comment: Actually, I'm out of ideas, too. Therefore I appreciate your effort very much. Normal and position textures are mixed up for sure. I switched them in my pipeline and the scene on the desktop looks like on the tablet before while on the tablet the scene is lit correctly then. Every rendering pass has its own frame buffer. But I noticed that I do not unbind the texture units for the next pass, I just overwrite the ones needed by the next pass. Could this cause the problem?

Comment: As far as I know, it shouldn't be a problem unless you're reading and writing a texture at the same time. But at this point it's probably worth trying anything to do with those textures now that you've narrowed it down to them being switched somehow. Good luck!

Comment: Tried resetting the texture units after each pass but it didn't helped. The error could be everywhere from scripting, where the rendering pipeline is defined, over my texture handling system and the render pass system, to less supported features or a driver bug by Intel. But I found out that normals and positions are really swapped, not only the normals are wrong. Because I inserted a point light which lit pixels in a small range of normal values instead of positions.